# building MATLAB jpeg toolbox with libjpeg8d

Tags: matlab, mex, libjpeg

This question is related to another question I asked here:

[Error reading image using jpeg_read from Matlab's jpeg toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932561/error-reading-image-using-jpeg-read-from-matlabs-jpeg-toolbox)

I've been trying to compile the jpeg toolbox under Windows 7 (using the commands Shai provided in the answer to the question I posted), but I get the following error:

```
jpeg_read.c(52) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'jerror.h': No such file or directory
```

which I believe happened because I haven't built libjpeg. I tried to build libjpeg6b like jpegtoolbox's README says, but I couldn't find a clear guide on how to do it on Windows with visual studio 2010 (and libjpeg's install document doesn't help much), so I ended building libjpeg8d.

My question is if there's any way to use libjpeg8d to compile the jpeg toolbox. I've tried running the command:

```
mex -I<IJGPATH> jpeg_read.c <LIBJPEG>
```

with IJGPATH being my libjpeg8d installation folder and LIBJPEG being the path to the jpeg.lib file, inside IJGPATH/Release, but I still get the same missing jerror.h error as before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From @Noam: "By the way, the toolbox file **jpegtbx_1.4.zip** can be found here: http://www.perigee.co.il/#!downloads/c4wn"

Answer (score 1):

Jpeg toolbox contains Matlab routines for manipulating JPEG files. While Matlab's built-in IMREAD and IMWRITE functions provide basic conversion between JPEG files and image arrays, they do not provide access to the details of the JPEG image, such as the JPEG coefficients or the quantization tables.

The routines in this package provide additional functionality for directly accessing the contents of JPEG files from Matlab, including the Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT) coefficients, quantization tables, Huffman coding tables, color space information, and comment markers. The toolbox can be added to Matlab to use the functions.

First check whether the following are installed in your system.

1.Microsoft windows sdk7
2.Microsoft visual c++ 2010 express

if they are not installed, Download and install them in the order specified.

Note: Before installing windows sdk, uninstall any redistributalbe packages of  visual c++ 2010.  Else windows sdk produces problem during installation and the install fails. During installation dont forget to check the 'x64 Libraries' for 64bit OS and 'x86 Libraries' for 32bit OS, under Windows Headers and Libraries. This allows to use compiler tools for 64 bit operating systems. Once it overs, install visual c++.  These tools are free and available at microsoft website. Both online and offline installers are available.
 Now comes the real integration process

Step 1: Download the jpeg toolbox and extract it to a separate folder (eg. jpeg)

Download jpeg toolbox

Step 2: Download jpeg source files and extract it to a separate folder (eg.jpegsrc). In the folder jpeg-6b which is in jpegsrc, rename jconfig.vc to jconfig.h and makefile.vc to makefile

Download jpegsrc file

Step 3: From start->All programs-> Microsoft windows sdk , open the command prompt. This opens the 'windows x64 debug environment'. Navigate to the jpeg-6b folder which is inside the jpegsrc folder which is extracted at step 2. Run the command 'nmake clean all' without quotes. This creates the libjpeg.lib file in the same folder.

Step 4: Now open the matlab and choose the workfolder as jpeg, created in step 1.

Now in the command windows run the following commands,
mex -I jpeg_read.c 
mex -I jpeg_write.c

Replace  with the path to the IJG jpeg-6b directory created in step 2, and
 with the full path to the IJG code library file (libjpeg.lib).

To use the jpeg_read and jpeg_write functions copy jpeg_read.mexw64 and jpeg_write.mexw64 files created above to your work directory. Dont uninstall visual c++ compiler or it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to work in Windows, you need to rename jerror.vc to jerror.h

Also, when you mex the files, you need to edit the jpeg_read.c and jpeg_write.c from include  to include "jerror.h"